# Determine if $p: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $p(a,b) = \frac {ab(b+1)}2$ is injective and/or surjective.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Determine if $$p: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N\quad \quad p(a,b) = \frac {ab(b+1)}2$$ is injective and/or surjective.

Just from looking at it and plugging in a few numbers I can already tell that this function is a bijection. However, I have no clue how to begin to prove that this is the case.

I am comfortable proving injectivity and surjectivity for functions with 1 variable but I get very confused when there is more than 1.

I could use some help generalizing a way of how to do this comfortably.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not injective: $p(5,2)=p(1,5)$.

Comment: And $p(3,4)=p(2,5)=p(5,3)$.

Comment: "Just from looking at it and plugging in a few numbers I can already tell that this function is a bijection." You can _never_ tell from just looking at it and plugging in a few values. Fermat's last theorem and the Riemann hypothesis wouldn't be such famously hard problems if that was a valid approach. My favourite example is the Polya conjecture (a statement about the prime decompositions of natural numbers) where the first counterexample is over $900\,000\,000$. You can't just "check a few values" and conclude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is surjective because $p(n,1)=n$. It is not injective because $p(5,2)=p(1,5)$.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this!  Just head on back to your first principles.

To show that p is injective, you need to show that if a,a',b,b' are natural numbers and p(a,b)=p(a',b') then it must be that a=a' and b=b'.  And to show that p is surjective, you need to show that if n is any natural number, that there are natural numbers a and b such that p(a,b)=n.